# Select the ID of last log

Tags: sql, oracle

I've an SQL select that is pretty simple to write in English but I can't achieve to translate it in SQL. Here it is:

> I want the ID of the latest event by user.

The table looks like this:

```
| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
|-------------|-----------|
| ID          | NUMBER    |
| OCCURED     | DATE      |
| USER_ID     | NUMBER    |
```

And I've try a lot of manipulations using `Max()`, some GroupBys:

```
SELECT l.user_id, MAX(l.OCCURED)
FROM USER_STATS.LOG l
group by l.user_id, l.occured
order by l.OCCURED DESC
```

but I didn't succeed.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reopened the question, because I think this is the simplest method:

One method that uses a single aggregation is to use `first`:

```
SELECT l.user_id, MAX(l.OCCURED),
       MAX(ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY l.OCCURRED DESC) as id_at_max
FROM USER_STATS.LOG l
GROUP BY l.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.user_id, MAX(l.OCCURED) as OCCURED 
FROM USER_STATS.LOG l
group by l.user_id
order by OCCURED DESC
```

I.e only `GROUP BY` user_id.